# Selecting pwm frequency for speed control of a dc motor?

Tags: pwm, dc-motor, h-bridge, l298

I am using **L298** motor driver to drive motors (12v , 900mA),I am using PWM to control motor speed but the problem is

1.When I set PWM frequency to 100 Hz motor work with jerks no noise at all.

2.When I set PWM frequency to 500 Hz motor work with little jerks and little noise.

3.When I set PWM frequency to 1000 Hz motor work with noise and no jerks at all.

4.When I set PWM frequency to 20 kHz motor dosen't work at all.

what should I do?

Comment: What kind of noise? The motors that I've seen make a constant high pitched noise at the PWM freq even when not moving. IIRC, the freq was considerably higher that 1 kHz.

Comment: Its zzzz or whining type of noise, it stops when motor is not moving and yes its considerably higher at 1kHz and above (till 1.5 kHz to 1.7 kHz)

Answer (score 1):

As long as your PWM frequency is in the audible range (50 - 15000 Hz), there will be some audible noise. It doesn't mean something is wrong or about to break, simply vibrations at those frequencies propagate through air and can be heard.

If you absolutely want to get rid of the noise, you'll need a frequency of 20 kHz or more. L298 has a maximum commutation frequency of 25 kHz, so you should be able to get it working at 20 kHz (at least at 40-60% duty cycle) if your PWM waveforms respect that limit. Perhaps if you display your PWM signals with an oscilloscope, you'll realize why it didn't work.

Comment: I did all that you have told me but none of them worked 
I have checked waveform its showing correct one but motor driver is not responding properly 
I think problem is with Motor driver only

Comment: Do you know any other motor driver similar to L298 with low cost?